# SharePoint SQL Server Databases are "Suspect" on every shutdown or reboot

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server-2012, database-server

I'll use this article: http://sharepointchips.com/recover-sharepoint-2013-databases-from-suspect-mode/

As a reference point.  What is happening is as described in the article, my SharePoint 2013 SP1 databases are going into "Suspect" mode at every reboot or shutdown.  My SQL Server is 2012 SP1 as well.  So far this hasn't been a huge concern (so far DBCC CheckDB has done a flawless repair job) but this is getting annoying.  This machine is my development virtual machine (VMWare Workstation 10 if it matters) so it shuts down and reboots often enough.  I can't imagine this is healthy for my server environment long term.  Any idea what is going on and how to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the best way to thwart SQL Server corruption on Shutdown with the SharePoint databases is at a SQL Prompt (In SQL Server Management Studio) shutting down SQL Server at the end of the day by using the command "SHUTDOWN" at the prompt.  So far no issues.

Answer (score 1):

This is common issue, it happens many ways( unavailable or corrupted database files, hardware failure) but most common is when  Server unexpectedly reboot or shutdown. We had this issue on one of our Developer's Laptop.

What we recommend before shutting down( as he did for weekend) the VM, please shut down the SQL server, it is small effort but save you at then end . Also keep the backup of your VM.

I would also recommend you investigate it i.e checking the logs and get why it is doing / which part causing this.

Comment: Useful precautions certainly, but logs haven't gotten me anywhere so far, nothing out of the ordinary noticed yet.

Answer (score 0):

A database will enter a 'suspect' state for a number of reasons and 2 of the main ones you can avoid are:

a) Try to avoid shutting down the database server when a timer job is writing to the database.  There are 2 ways to avoid this, one is to ensure you shutdown the 'sharepoint' servers before you shutdown the database server.  The other way is to ensure you never trigger a shutdown of the database server on the 5 min time interval so as to hopefully miss a clash with any sharepoint timer jobs.

b) Be kind to the servers and do not force a shutdown.  So if you are using VMs, ensure you shutdown the Guest Operating System and don't just power off the server.  Or log onto the server and request a shutdown through the OS.